# Set permission for folders/files in magento

Tags: javascript, magento-1.7

How can I set permission to folders and files in Magento without using SSH/FTP. I am stuck here, my Magento website does not load JavaScript and CSS
that is why I can login into admin panel. Means I can't set permission from admin panel.

I do not know how to use SSH and FTP so please explain how can I set permission to files and folders?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can contact your hosting provider and ask them to reset the permission.